# Can I run several TKL appliances on one server box (eg, HP Microserver)?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm interested in by Ubuntu-based TurnKey Linux (TKL)'s many (apparently) ready-to-use, FOSS appliances. Is it possible to create one server box (without virtualization) that runs more than one TKL appliance?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot run more than one appliance on one physical machine!

What you need is this: http://bitnami.org/stacks